# Error of type: PID: 6445 - Mongodb in android app

Tags: android, runtime-error, realm

I have seem to isolate the error of my previous question to this component in the app. Any idea to why this is making the app crash? (The crash happens when I press a button trying to go to this screen)

Appreciate as always the feedback!

```
    init {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            MongoDB.getData().collect {
                data.value = it
            }
        }
    }
```

Get data component:

```
    override fun getData(): Flow<List<Person>> {
        return realm.query<Person>().asFlow().map { it.list }
    }
```

This was how the previous error looked like:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.groundzero, PID: 15617
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.example.groundzero.mongodb.mongohomescreen.HomeViewModel$1.invokeSuspend(HomeViewModel.kt:27)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@43b8bcc, Dispatchers.Main]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [RLM_ERR_NO_SUCH_TABLE]: No such table exists
at io.realm.kotlin.internal.interop.CoreErrorConverter.asThrowable(CoreErrorConverter.kt:42)
at io.realm.kotlin.internal.interop.realmcJNI.realm_get_class(Native Method)
at io.realm.kotlin.internal.interop.realmc.realm_get_class(realmc.java:558)
at io.realm.kotlin.internal.interop.RealmInterop.realm_get_class-nILuwFE(RealmInterop.kt:304)
at io.realm.kotlin.internal.schema.CachedSchemaMetadata.<init>(CachedClassKeyMap.kt:101)
at io.realm.kotlin.internal.LiveRealmReference.<init>(RealmReference.kt:108)
at io.realm.kotlin.internal.ConfigurationImpl.openRealm$suspendImpl(ConfigurationImpl.kt:108)
at io.realm.kotlin.internal.ConfigurationImpl.openRealm(Unknown Source:0)
at io.realm.kotlin.mongodb.internal.SyncConfigurationImpl.openRealm(SyncConfigurationImpl.kt:114)
at io.realm.kotlin.internal.RealmImpl$1.invokeSuspend(RealmImpl.kt:107)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:280)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:85)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:59)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source:1)
at io.realm.kotlin.internal.platform.CoroutineUtilsSharedJvmKt.runBlocking(CoroutineUtilsSharedJvm.kt:22)
at io.realm.kotlin.internal.platform.CoroutineUtilsSharedJvmKt.runBlocking$default(CoroutineUtilsSharedJvm.kt:21)
at io.realm.kotlin.internal.RealmImpl.<init>(RealmImpl.kt:106)
at io.realm.kotlin.internal.RealmImpl.<init>(Unknown Source:0)
at io.realm.kotlin.internal.RealmImpl$Companion.create$io_realm_kotlin_library(RealmImpl.kt:263)
at io.realm.kotlin.Realm$Companion.open(Realm.kt:82)
at com.example.groundzero.mongodb.data.MongoDB.configureTheRealm(MongoDB.kt:40)
at com.example.groundzero.mongodb.data.MongoDB.<clinit>(MongoDB.kt:26)
... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you show how the ```getData()```  works?

Comment: yes will add it shortly!

Comment: The stack trace has some hints of accessing a table that is not existing.

Comment: but I made it so the table should be created automatically and the user can then enter their personal information like age. Will it work if I manually create the table?